Steam Shower Vapor/Water Proofing. Installation before walls go up
Good day
Need help in building the steam shower. Its been a long time coming. The framing part is pretty much done.
The bench on the left will be built tomorrow to complete the L shape - decided to go with 17 inches in depth.
The waterfall head will be right above the drain.
The pitch is being built tomorrow about an inch higher off the current tile and will be covered with another tile.
The steam linear head will be located on the same side of the fixtures across the left bench.
Few questions:

Liner - Does the liner need extend all the way to the back or start at the end of the bench? I have a piece of 6x9. The floor square footage is about 40.

DUROCK cement board - purchased 5/8 cement board which will be applied directly to the frame.

Redguard - I bought 3.5 gallons would this be enough to account for the 30mil thickness to qualify for full vapor proof barrier? (something I read on one of the forums here in regards to 30mil thickness)

Shower body - the one installed now is non thermostatic. Please suggest one along with a shower kit. Thank you. I want to change it before the walls go up.

Bench size/design: The depth 17 inches. The heigh 18?

Te pitch would be raised about an inch off the floor. any suggestion as to waterproofing...


I will have a waterfall shower had installed which is directly over the drain. The Metal pipe sticking out next to it is something I saw in a European Bathhouse and installed it here. Its basically a Flushometer connected to a cold waterline and when pulled pours cold water over you (hence the flush) Its great after a sauna session :).
Please let me know if i missed anything. Thank you. The installers are coming in tomorrow. Would love to get some insights before they start working further.
PS any suggestions in regards to recessed lighting and fan installation inside/outside the steam room would be appreciated
enter image description here
pg


I dunno, but a non-Thermostatic valve for the amount of money you are putting in to the project is a bit penny-wise, pound foolish. Please, God, let it at least be pressure balanced.
